# USB wakeup from suspended state on Android 13.x IMX8MQ evk

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-source

I am unable to use USB wake-up feature of Android on IMX8MQ evk.

I am using the following setup:

```
-Imx8mq EVK
-Android 13
-Kernel 5.15.71-dirty
-GSM modem is attached via USB
```

I have set the following configurations in adb shell

```
$echo auto > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/control
$echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup
```

Then I use the following command to suspend the Android

```
$ echo freeze > sys/power/state
```

This makes the Android go to suspended state but  if I send SMS or Call on the modem then Android doesn't wakeup. I have to wake it up using the on/off button on imx8mq board.

The dmesg logs show

```
[ 261.447647] [ T2070] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[ 261.492072] [ T2070] Filesystems sync: 0.039 seconds
[ 261.497027] [ T2070] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
[ 261.508140] [ T2070] OOM killer disabled.
[ 261.512084] [ T2070] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[ 261.527000] [ T2070] [drm] Reg val is 0x0080
[ 261.635878] [ T2070] [drm] hdmi phy shutdown complete
[ 261.688235] [ T143] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
[ 332.909844] [ C0] PM: pm_system_irq_wakeup: 37 triggered 30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey
[ 332.931925] [ T2070] [drm] Pixel clock: 148500 KHz, character clock: 148500, bpc is 8-bit, fmt 1
[ 332.940661] [ T2070] [drm] VCO frequency is 5940000 KHz
[ 332.995653] [ T2070] [drm] Mode: 1920x1080p148500
[ 333.039877] [ T2070] [drm] Pixel clock: 148500 KHz, character clock: 148500, bpc is 8-bit, fmt 1
[ 333.048594] [ T2070] [drm] VCO frequency is 5940000 KHz
[ 333.131966] [ T2070] [drm] No vendor infoframe
[ 333.374189] [ T2070] OOM killer enabled.
[ 333.378069] [ T2070] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 333.386479] [ T2070] Resume caused by IRQ 37, 30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey
[ 333.390998] [ T419] healthd: battery l=85 v=3 t=35.0 h=2 st=2 c=400000 fc=4000000 cc=32 chg=au
[ 333.393671] [ T2070] PM: suspend exit
[ 333.526105] [ T143] android_work: did not send uevent (0 0 0000000000000000)
[ 333.526243] [ T552] read descriptors
[ 333.538834] [ T552] read strings
[ 334.389181] [ T1] init: Untracked pid 2070 exited with status 0
[ 334.396626] [ T1] init: Untracked pid 2070 did not have an associated service entry and will not be reaped
[ 334.498085] [ T20] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
[ 334.649956] [ T20] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
```

The USB enumeration

```
[ 53.799900] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci-hcd
[ 53.909564] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1546, idProduct=1342, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 53.918672] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[ 54.099461] [ T20] option 1-1.3:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 54.107372] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 54.117025] [ T20] option 1-1.3:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 54.125232] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 54.134651] [ T20] option 1-1.3:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 54.142854] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 54.152350] [ T20] option 1-1.3:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 54.160511] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[ 54.194934] [ T20] qmi_wwan 1-1.3:1.4: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[ 54.208145] [ T20] qmi_wwan 1-1.3:1.4 wwan0: register 'qmi_wwan' at usb-xhci-hcd.0.auto-1.3, WWAN/QMI device, 02:4f:9d:5b:0b:f3
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong here and how should I investigate the issue.

Comment: Seems like this question is more for [unix.se] or [su]. It's not a programming question, and is off-topic here.